# Background image for H1 heading

Tags: html, css, background-image

In my wordpress theme page heading `<?php the_title(); ?>` .

My Css:

```
#page h1.pagetitle {
      width:auto;
      text-align:left;
      font-size:30px;
      padding:25px 40px 25px 0px;
      text-transform:uppercase;
    }

     #page h1.pagetitle span{
     background:#202020; 
     padding:5px 40px 5px 10px;
     }
```

Html:

```
<h1 class="pagetitle"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h1>
```

I want background image like arrow ribbon like this sample http://www.123rf.com/photo_12816420_green-arrow-ribbon-on-wooden-desk.html

I can place background Image directly or using background image with repeat-x.But My page title text span width is not fix at all the time. Each page is with different page title .

So I want to use two Image portion 
:one with  rectangular behind text using repeat-x and
:second with arrow (triangular) just after end of text string.

this way I can get the arrow image for any page title text.
Suggest me how can I get this?

Comment: Maybe you have to use `:after` take a look there: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/

Comment: Thanks@ChoiZ for help link , I am also going through this topic http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?767250-How-to-start-a-background-image-after-the-text-ends

Comment: So in your paste code we can't see :after ;)

Comment: Just I am Trying it , I will post it .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this technique a lot:

```
h1{
    background: url('http://i49.tinypic.com/2zs1z79.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 25px;
    padding:0 10px;
    height:40px;
}

h1:before,h1:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background:inherit;
    background-position:100% 100%;
}
h1:before {
    left:-20px;
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

I use `:before` and `:after` for the head and the tail and a sprite for the image. It is nice, clean and flexible (enough).

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/5Qvn7/

Comment: Thanks@xpy : this is really helpful , This is what I want to get.just trying it.

Comment: Its working! Now I can Implement it what I want for any different ribbon Image using Image-sprite.