# Adding a shaped border-bottom to the section heading

Tags: css

I am looking for a design like the following screenshot for the section heading. ( **The bottom line**)

[image]

So far I could achieve

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #8d8f90;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-transform: none">How it works</h1>
```

Now I want the both end of the `border-bottom` to be shaped.

Comment: I guess your best bet is to use a svg as border with the right shape. Even with `:before` and `:after` you wouldn't get this shape unless you use `cli-path` but that support is limited

Comment: Looks like something to do with SVG. Otherwise, you'll need quite a bit of CSS, with various elements, to mimick this.

Comment: @SuperDJ Since I am not familiar with svg and stuffs can you give a bit help to solve this

Comment: @GolezTrol Since I am not familiar with svg and stuffs can you give a bit help to solve this

Comment: You could try with setting a backgorund image like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730533/background-image-for-h1-heading

Comment: @Lricsi From my experience setting a image will be a real mess in responsive

Comment: using an image wont mess with the responsive unless its a really large image. From the looks of the example shown, that title is very short so even on screens @400px or less will not need to be shrunk down, and even if it did it would not noticeably affect the image quality.

Comment: @Moose Thank you for your kind explanation. This a wordpress site and I am working on visual composer plugin. I am providing a element for client that client can **edit the heading** as he wanted. I can limit the client's expectation. That's where I got stucked :-(

Comment: @Ramesh : no problems. Ah i see. Well if i was you i would set the border he wants as a background image for that header. you can then use media queries to keep the image at a reasonable size for responsive. Would you like me to provide an answer with a more in depth explanation/example?

Comment: @Moose yeah it will be better if you can come up with an example. At the mean time I looking for some articles about svg. If I will be able to create a svg as I wanted I will go ahead with it.

Comment: does the border have to be the same size length as the text in the header?

Comment: @Moose Not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of using responsive background-image as requested in comments!

So im assuming that the border image will need to be that same length as the text, here is a working example:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(https://ded7t1cra1lh5.cloudfront.net/media/76045/a7fdf291661d9baab9b767d833c70183ba6ee3ce/original/divider-37709_1280.png?1448468523);
  height: 120px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover/*contain*/
  ;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="_1">I am a header</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <h1 id="_2">I am a really really really really long header</h1>
</div>
```

So in this i grabbed a pretty large image from google as an example so it wouldnt be stretched at larger screen sizes. You will need to use @media screen command to alter the height of the header tag when the text breaks. However this will only be needed on longer headers, and if the header border needs to be the same length as the text. If it doesnt you can use a much shorter image and possibly change the size from cover to contain. The inline block makes it so the background image will always be the length of the text as well.

If you do decide to go this route some minor tweaking to the css should yield you acceptable results. Hope this is helpful as a back up solution Ramesh!

Comment: Thank you for you time and well explained answer.This seems fine. But in the responsive I can see few collision. If I will unable to create the svg this will help me alot. Thank you

Comment: No problems. Yes there will be a few collisions with the random image i grabbed off google. Using an image you have prepared yourself for the situation should help alleviate that. Best of luck.

Comment: I worked on svg and did the job, but later I found the load of the svg is more than the image in my case. So I've worked through your solution. Thank you.